# Reading files with Node is returning empty object outside the reading code

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read files with Node and then create a Object with the information that I extract from those files. I used the fs and path libs. I defined a empty Object outside the code that read the files, inside that code (where I use callbacks) the defined object get it's values modified, but outside it's value remain empty. Can someone help me?
Here is my code:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, "query");

let Query = {};

fs.readdir(dirPath, (error, files) => {
  if (error) {
    return console.log(error);
  }

  files.forEach((file) => {
    const loaded = require(path.join(dirPath, file));

    Object.entries(loaded).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      Query[key] = value;
    });
  });
});

module.exports = {
  Query,
};
```

When I ran `console.log(Query)` above the `module.exports` I got `{}` as answer, however running the same before the callback from `fs.readdir` ends return me the correct object.

I am not sure if the problem is non blocking IO or if I defined the object the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.readdir` is an asynchronous function, which means, the rest of the script will keep running without waiting the callback in `readdir` to finish.

Hence, the object `Query` will still print `{}` - it hasn't changed yet.

You want to continue your program only after reading the file.

One way to do this is to use `readdirSync` instead of `readdir` which is an synchronous function. Then, only when it is done, the program will continue.

Your code using `readdirSync`:

```
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");

const dirPath = path.join(__dirname, "query");

let Query = {};

fs.readdirSync(dirPath).forEach((file) => {
    const loaded = require(path.join(dirPath, file));
    Object.entries(loaded).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      Query[key] = value;
    });

console.log(Query); // Should return the desired object

module.exports = {
  Query,
};
```